# Cannot attach database SQL Server 2012 error 5

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

When I type this:

```
CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
ON (FILENAME = 'C:\Users\sohm\Desktop\Pohm\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG ;
```

I get this:

> *File activation failure. The physical file name
>   "C:\Users\sohm\Desktop\AdventureWorks2012_Data_log.ldf" may be incorrect.*
>   *Msg 5123, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5 (Access is denied.) while attempting to
>   open or create the physical file 'C:\adventuredb\AdventureWorks2012_Data_log.ldf'.
>
>   Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
>   Could not open new database 'AdventureWorks2012'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.*

I know it has to do with permissions.  I have the administrator account.  I have read a million posts but nothing has worked so far.  Also when I try to change the folder containing the mdf file, to full control but it keeps reverting back to read-only.

Comment: Make sure it is not attached already, SQL server takes full control of MDF files.

Comment: I did, the db is not attached

Comment: Make sure that the account running the sql server service has full control over that folder as it will need to read the MDF and create a new LDF file in there. Ignore the read only attribute on the folder, it's generally ignored in windows and is used mostly for folder customisation.

Comment: I am logged in Windows with the default admin account.  How do I set full control over the folder?  Because when I right click the folder and go to security, I have full access.

Comment: You could be logged on as God, SQL Server is not you.

Answer (score 10):

You should run SSMS as an administrator.
Also it is possible that you might be running query as an 'sa' user(sql server authentication).
Try running the query with windows Authentication.

Comment: This simple solution worked for me (run as admin) but I'm still very curious of what is the problem when permission for the folder and file is full control for eveyone

Answer (score 3):

**SHORT VERSION**

For allowing MS SQL server 2012 to attach the database files you must grant full access to the mdf and ldf files to:

> NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
>
> Full Access

**LONG VERSION**

SQL Security has been updated a lot in 2012 handling of files. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189128.aspx

If you look at the existing attached databases and there security you will probably see that there only are 2 roles allowed with full access. **MSSQLSERVER** and **Administrators**, when attached SQL Removes all other roles from the files.

Trying to set the MSSQLSERVER from the fil security Permission will not work.

Looking at your services.msc overview you will in a default install see that NT Service\MSSQLSERVER also runs the SQL server servics.

The service account is not visible, the same issue as with IIS AppPools, a sub group has been created by the system and "hides" the accounts from auto discovery, probably to try and secure the accounts but in my view just obscures the setup.

Regards 
Jan

Comment: You can also Enable Inheritance for each file which would grant the same permissions as the directory. Typically this would be Full control by the admins groups.

Comment: Hi Woody, you r proposed solution does not work on 2012. See the last sentence on the problem description.

Answer (score 2):

Open the SQL Server Management Stdio in Administrator mode(Right click -> Select Run as Administrator. If it asks for User name and password enter your Administrator user name password). Then select Windows Authentication click ok, and now try to attache it will attache without any error.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with YOUR account. SQL Server is trying to write to that folder under the context of the service account that is running SQL Server. You can see who this is by going to the Services applet and seeing who the instance runs as (probably NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM or whatever). You can override that or you can place your MDF files in the data folder, which SQL Server already has inherent access to, instead of placing them in this other location on your C:\ drive.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to change all the SQL Server services to Local System Account instead of services. Start -> Run ->Services.msc -> Scroll down to SQL Server, you should see five services that start with SQL Server. Right-Click, Properties, Log On, change to Local System Account.  Repeat for all the rest of the SQL Server Services and restart them all.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

Go to the folder where you have stored `mdf` file.

Select `file -> Right click -> click` on mdf give **full permissions** to file for logged in user Security.

If still issue persist and it might me because of corrupted transaction logs, you may use tool [SQL Database Recovery Tool Repairs](https://www.stellarinfo.com/sql-recovery.php) to repair your corrupted mdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I went to sql server configuration manager and right clicked SQL Server Service.  Then I added my Windows Admin account to run the service and now it works.